# Is it possible to draw a cone which never intersects any grid points?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, analytic-geometry

I am wondering if it is possible to define first a line, $z = my + b$ such that when the line is revolved around the $z$ axis to form a cone, this cone never intersects any integer grid points.

In other words, is it possible to define a surface of revolution by the above method such that there are no points $(a,b,c)$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ which intersect the surface?

What about a cone which only intersects the origin?

There is a simple proof to show that a line $z = m y$, with $m \notin \mathbb{Q}$  [edited from $m \notin \mathbb{Z}$ ] never intersects any integer grid points (other than (0,0)), but I am not sure if it is very clear how to generalise this to a surface of revolution.

Comment: Sure: $z = \pi y + e$

Comment: Note:  your example is incorrect.  The line $z=\frac 12 y$ goes through infinitely many grid points, for instance.  I think you meant to say $m\notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: You could take $z = \alpha y + \gamma$ where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are transcendental numbers. For only the origin take $z = \alpha y$. The choice is yours and you have infinite possible lines.

Comment: If you need a more detailed answer on how to pick the transcendental numbers (not all pairs work) I can write an answer.

Comment: Yes, lulu, thank you.

Comment: Muhammad, I would be interested in a further proof, yes please! Do the numbers need to be transcendental, or will irrational numbers do?

Also, does this apply also to a line revolved about an axis?

Comment: Are you sure this is an elementary number theory question?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cone $z=\pi  +\sqrt {x^2 +y^2}$.

This cone does not have a point with integral coordinates at all. Otherwise $\pi$ would be rational.

Comment: OP was interested in cones that miss all the lattice points, not just the ones on the coordinate planes.  I believe this still works. If you replace the $\sqrt 3$ with something transcendental it is clear.

Comment: Like $\phi$, $\pi$, $e$, $e\pi$, $e\pi\phi$, e.t.c.

Comment: I was hoping for more info on surfaces of revolution created by lines. More specifically, I am wondering if one can show whether or not Muhammad's $z = \alpha y + \gamma$ can miss all lattice points in 3D when revolved about an axis.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2=\left(z+\frac12\right)^2$$ has no integer solutions.